# dynamic anychart with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, anychart

I have some problems when I using anychart with ajax.
Because data of anychart is dependent on the check_box users select, I have to ajax the data.
the basic form of chart is fine, but selected data do not work on the chart

Here is my code.

```
<body>
 <div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question_id' value='1'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question_id' value='2'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question_id' value='3'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question_id' value='4'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question_id' value='5'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='question_id' value='6'>
 <div>
 <button id='report'>report</button>
 <div id='container'></div>

</body>
```

---

and my ajax and anychart setting is as below

```
<script>
  $(function() {
   $('#report').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
        ids: $("input[name='question_id']:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
        }).get()
       },



     });

   });
  });

  anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
   var dataSet = anychart.data.set(<%= select_data %>);
   var chart = anychart.column();
   ......
   ......
   chart.container('container');
   chart.draw();

  });
</script>
```

I am thinking that I have to rerender the anychart so the ajax data could be loaded, but I have no idea how to make it work

Comment: Can you share a working (not working sample)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't apply changes to data.

When you receive the new data you should apply it to a chart, it can be done like this:

dataSet = anychart.data.set(newData);

or

chart.data(newData);

Also, in your code chart and data variables are local within onDocumentReady function.

Answer (score 0):

```
anychart.onDocumentLoad(function() {
            $.getJSON("dataurl", function(result) {
                var dataSet = anychart.data.set(result);
                var chart = anychart.column();

                chart.column(dataSet.mapAs({ value: 1, x: 0 })).name('Inventory');
                chart.column(dataSet.mapAs({ value: 2, x: 0 })).name('Sales');

                chart.grid(0, { layout: 'vertical' })
                chart.barGroupsPadding(3)

                chart.legend(true);
                chart.title('Compare sales strategy')
                chart.yScale().minimum(0);
                chart.container('container');
                chart.draw();
            })
        });
```